# System.out.println Line Affecting Execution of the Logic

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement, boolean-logic, system.out

I have run into an incredibly strange phenomenon. I am currently programming an instant messenger program in Java and I have a variable to represent whether a new user has connected (this is of in a separate class). Here is the code in question where the object `ListenerThread extends Thread` :

```
boolean listenerThreadConnected = ServerDriver.getListenerThread().connected;
System.out.println("Whatever in here");
if(listenerThreadConnected){
    ...
    System.out.println("In the if statement");
    ...
}
```

So, this code works. When `listenerThreadConnected = true` the `if` statement executes and it outputs `In the if statement` and does all of the other stuff in the if statement. However, I changed no other code other than commenting out the `System.out.println("Whatever in here")` and the `if` statement didn't trigger and there was no sign of the `In the if statement` being outputted. My code looked like this:

```
boolean listenerThreadConnected = ServerDriver.getListenerThread().connected;
//System.out.println("Whatever in here");
if(listenerThreadConnected){
    ...
    System.out.println("In the if statement");
    ...
}
```

I am quite perplexed. How could this `System.out.println` affect the actual logic? I know this question is very open-ended, but have you ever had a similar experience? For some context, this is all in a `while` loop and ListenerThread is a concurrently running Thread. I can't seem to replicate this result except in my current code.

**[EDIT]** Replacing the `System.out.println` with a `Thread.sleep(1)` also seems to work, so this leads me to think that it is a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not so extrange at all, you are for sure in a multi thread system and your app is getting an outdated `boolean` value, you need to ensure memory visibility when reading the variable **listenerThreadConnected**

**How:?**

Declare this `boolean listenerThreadConnected` as volatile and the error must be gone!

Comment: Thanks so much. Pretty new to multi threading and concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `System.out.println` is often implemented as `synchronized` (even though this isn't documented), in order that you don't get the output of two threads interleaving.

Executing that statement has the effect of making updates to variables visible to the thread in which the synchronized method is executed (it is a "happens before" relationship).

By removing the `System.out.println` call, you remove this behaviour, so you may see outdated variables.

As @Xoce웃Пepeúpa says, make the variable `volatile`, or do something else to ensure memory visibility (e.g. changing it to an `AtomicBoolean`).